# General SQL/MySQL turning rows into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I am currently struggling a bit with MySQL in trying to pivot a table.

A simplified version of the table itself would probably be something along the lines of:

```
 dayName      amount
---------------------
Monday         34
Tuesday        3453
...            ...
```

Ideally I would like to be able to turn each day into a column and each amount as its value.
Any suggestion on to do it in a clean way?

Thanks!

Comment: Will the rows always have the same values? E.g., are they always the days of the week?

Comment: Hey @DeadEnd -- have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your rows are always the days of the week, then you can use something like this:

```
select 
sum(case when dayName = 'Monday' then amount end) as 'Monday',
sum(case when dayName = 'Tuesday' then amount end) as 'Tuesday' 
.
.
.
from DaysOfWeek;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a `PIVOT` function.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1a11/6